# Step through items in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so:

```
{'AAAGGG': ['AGAGAGAA', 'AGAGAGAG'], 'AAAGGC': ['AGAGAGAG']})
```

I want to step through each key and then step through the chars of its corresponding values. So something like this:

```
for key in myDict:
    for eachValue in key:
        for char in eachValue:
            do something
```

Hopefully there is an easy way of doing this.

Comment: So you want to do something for every character in the _values_, right?

Comment: Can I ask what you're doing for each character? There might be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Python Tutorial: Looping Techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

When you have the key, use the key to look up the value.  Don't iterate through the key.

```
for key in myDict:
    for eachValue in myDict[key]:
        for char in eachValue:
            do something
```

More efficiently, iterate through the items and avoid the extra lookup:

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    for eachValue in value:
        for char in eachValue:
            do something
```

Comment: *avoid the extra lookup* - I am not sure if it can be called an extra look up

Comment: @thefourtheye the iterator already has the key and value as it proceeds through the bucket chains;  retrieving a value by key involves hashing the key then proceeding through the bucket chain to find the entry with the key

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
my_dict = {'AAAGGG': ['AGAGAGAA', 'AGAGAGAG'], 'AAAGGC': ['AGAGAGAG']})

for parent_value in my_dict.values():
    for sub_value in parent_value:
        for char in sub_value:
            do_something(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable({'long_key': ["abc", "cdef"], 'another_key':['ZYC', 'hgt']}.keys()))
#  ['a', 'n', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', '_', 'k', 'e', 'y', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'g', '_', 'k', 'e', 'y']
```